# how to convert date to this format 2015-02-27T15:14:13-06:00

Tags: java, java-7

I need to convert date to this format 2015-02-27T15:14:13-06:00

I have tried with `SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");` , but this one generating as 2015-04-09T10:39:19-04

Tks

Comment: Try setting the timezone: `fmt.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "whatever timezone you need" ) );`

Comment: Oh, I guess you mean the difference in the offset format, i.e. `-06:00` instead of `-04`. Please be a bit more specific next time so that we  don't have to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the new Yoda time which has ISO date formatters and parsers or you can use a `SimpleDateFormat` of *"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"* which gives you "ccyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+zzzz" and insert the extra colon manually.

Something like:

```
new StringBuilder(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").format(date)).insert(22,':').toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks oldcurmudgeon. I needed to set timezone and add your logic to insert : at 22nd position

```
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        fmt.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Central"));
        System.out.println("date to str:"+(new StringBuilder(fmt.format(new Date())).insert(22,':')));
```