# Formatting ISO 8601 date with a colon seperator

Tags: java, date, iso8601

I am trying to convert the date in milliseconds to the following ISO 8601 format:

[image]

But I am getting the following using SimpleDateFormat:

```
    /**
     * It converts the time from long to the ISO format
     * 
     * @param timestampMillis
     * @return isoDate
     */
    public String convertTimeMillisToISO8601(String timestampMillis)
    {
        long timeInLong= Long.parseLong(timestampMillis);
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String isoDate = df.format(new java.util.Date(timeInLong));
        return isoDate;
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
"ts":"2015-06-18T09:56:21+0000"
```

I know I can use substring to append the extra colon but Is there any better way to do so ?

Comment: Did you try `X` for the timezone?

Comment: based on this question and answer i think it's not supported in Java `SimpleDateFormat`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: @Tichodroma - yes, all it prints is for UTC it will print Z.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always [use a StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29544129/823393):

```
new StringBuilder(
      new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
      .format(date))
    .insert(22,':')
    .toString();
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 8):

For Java 7 and higher, you might use `XXX` (ISO 8601 time zone) in the date format String. According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), the result of `X` can be:

```
X    => -08
XX   => -0800
XXX  => -08:00
```

but for all of those, it might as well return `Z`!

For Java 6 and earlier, there is no `X` ([J6 doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)), and since the result of `X` may or may not do what you want, I strongly recommend you just insert that colon yourself.

Comment: `X` will produce `Z` for UTC, not `+00:00`.

Comment: Yes, it says so in the documentation I liked to. It may generate the desired result, or `Z`. That's why I would really just insert the colon myself.

Answer (score 1):

For Java 8 if you use one of the standard `ISO_DATE_*` format patterns then the **output** formatted String will be truncated when the offset is +00:00 (UTC typically just appends `Z`).

```
OffsetDateTime utcWithFractionOfSecond = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-01-10T12:00:00.000000+00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);

utcWithFractionOfSecond.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);     // 2018-01-10T12:00:00Z ... not what you want!
```

The only solution I have found is using the `outputPattern` (shown below) that uses **lowercase** `xxx' to ensure that a colon is included in the timezone offset.

I have included an example with factions-of-a-second for completeness (you can remove the `SSSSSS` in your case)

```
DateTimeFormatter inputPattern = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
DateTimeFormatter outputPattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSxxx");

OffsetDateTime utcWithFractionOfSecond = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-01-10T12:00:00.000000+00:00", inputPattern);
OffsetDateTime utcNoFractionOfSecond = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-01-10T12:00:00+00:00", inputPattern);
OffsetDateTime utcWithZ = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-01-10T12:00:00Z", inputPattern);
OffsetDateTime utcPlus3Hours = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-01-10T12:00:00.000000+03:00", inputPattern);|

utcWithFractionOfSecond.format(outputPattern );     // 2018-01-10T12:00:00.000000+00:00
utcNoFractionOfSecond.format(outputPattern);        // 2018-01-10T12:00:00.000000+00:00
utcWithZ.format(outputPattern);                     // 2018-01-10T12:00:00.000000+00:00
utcPlus3Hours.format(outputPattern);                // 2018-01-10T12:00:00.000000+03:00
```

In these examples I have used ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME only to create the input values for the test cases. In all cases it is the outputPattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSxxx` that controlling how to include a colon character in the timezone portion of your resulting formatted string.

*Note that if your input data included the Zone ID like `[Europe/London]` then you would create your input data using ZonedDateTime instead of OffsetDateTime*

Comment: The input string indicates only an offset, not a time zone. So `OffsetDateTime` class is appropriate here, not `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Agreed, I have updated the answer to be more specific about using `OffsetDateTime` in this particular example

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Java 8?

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
System.out.println(formatter.format(ZonedDateTime.now()));
```

> 2015-04-15T17:24:19+09:00

Comment: Also for UTC? That's where the XXX went wrong for the `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: For UTC it will print `Z`

Comment: @Raniz - yes so I am talking about UTC.

Comment: No need to specify a formatting pattern. The standard ISO 8601 format of the input string is handled by default in the *java.time* classes.

Comment: The `OffsetDateTime` is appropriate here with this Question, as the input involves `+00:00`. No time zone is indicated in the Question, so `ZonedDateTime` is not the best fit.

Comment: This Answer does not address the Question. The Question asked for parsing a string, not capturing the current moment.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2014-06-18T09:56:21+00:00" )
```

> 2014-06-18T09:56:21Z

## Details

Some other answers are close, correct in using the modern *java.time* classes that supplanted the terrible old legacy classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`). But they are either working too hard or chose the wrong class.

### ISO 8601

Your format is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating text representing their date-time values. So you need not specify any formatting pattern at all. Works by default.

### `OffsetDateTime`

Your input indicates an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours and zero minutes. So we should use the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class.

```
String input = "2014-06-18T09:56:21+00:00";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input );
```

#### Zulu time

We can generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format by merely calling `toString`. The `Z` on the end means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), and is pronounced “Zulu”.

> odt.toString(): 2014-06-18T09:56:21Z

### `ZonedDateTime`

If your input indicated a time zone, rather than merely an offset, we would have used [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class. An offset is simply a number of hours, minutes, and seconds – nothing more. A time zone is *much* more. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).